# Android EdittextPreference Hint (android:hint)

Tags: android, android-edittext, preference, hint, preferencescreen

I have a preference screen with an EditTextPreference.
How to set a hint

either in xml like

```
android:hint
```

or in code like

```
setHint(int), setHint(CharSequence hint)
```

on the EditTextPreference like on an EditText field?
I assumed that it´s like on the EditText but i didn´t find anything like this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`android:summary`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3asummary) to give a brief description of your preference.

You can also set this dynamically using [`setSummary(CharSequence summary)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) .

**EDIT:** for giving a 'hint' you could use [`android:defaultValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adefaultValue) .

Comment: i know this, but is there no way to set a hint like on an edittext field?

Comment: i already set the summary dynamically and defaultvalue is not really what i´m looking for, but anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It's exactly the same to set a hint in XML for an EditTextPreference as it is for an EditText:

```
android:hint="This is my hint"
```

This gets passed through to the EditText in the dialog.

This behaviour is confirmed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html) where it says "It is a subclass of DialogPreference and shows the EditText in a dialog. This EditText can be modified either programmatically via getEditText(), or through XML by setting any EditText attributes on the EditTextPreference."

Comment: I can confirm that it works (CM 7,1). Thanks. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

this is way better, as the accepted answer will not set a hint on the edittext but will set the text to
the EditText (long live the small differene).

To really set a hint, use this code:

```
YourEditTextPreference.getEditText().setHint(R.string.some_hint);
```

you may also consider adding a summary so the preference will not be displayed with an empty summary

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer as well, e.g. as to why it is better.

Comment: this method has since been deprecated and removed. you can no longer access EditText from the EditTextPreference.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the AndroidX preference library, you can assign a hint using an `OnBindEditTextListener` in your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```java
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
    EditTextPreference textPref = manager.findPreference("myTextPreference");
    textPref.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
            editText.setHint(R.string.hint);
        }
    });
}
```

When the input field is empty, the hint should then be displayed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin version (AndroidX preference library)**:

```
val editTextPref = findPreference<Preference>("prefKey") as EditTextPreference
editTextPref.setOnBindEditTextListener {
    it.hint = "My hint"
}
```

Works in emulator with Android 10 (API level 29).

At the same time, the **hint specified in xml does not work**:

```
<EditTextPreference
                android:key="prefKey"
                android:title="Title"
                android:hint="My hint"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

the way to set "Hints" is to use a summary provider as described in 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings

the idea is to print a default/hint when the value is null or empty - otherwise, just print out the preference value

```
val dobPreference: EditTextPreference? = findPreference("key_dob")

dobPreference?.summaryProvider = SummaryProvider<EditTextPreference> { pref ->

    if (pref.text.isNullOrBlank()) {
        "e.g. Enter your DOB in DDMMYYYY format" // the hint if pref is empty
    } else {
        pref.text // your preference value if it is not empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the `android:hint` value in your answer. The `SummaryProvider` is not needed here.